# Visual Studio connection to mysql database

Tags: c++, mysql-connector

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ueek.png)So, I am attempting to connect to a local mysql database and I cannot seem to get the libraries to be recognized so far this is what i have for the property config

```
Error: "cannot open source file "mysql_connection", "cppconn/driver.h"...cppconn/statement.h"

these are the files paths i used for the configurations[enter image description here][1]
C/C++/general/additionalincludelibraries:
C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\include
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include
A:\Program Files\boost_1_74_0\boost_1_74_0

Linker/AdditionalLibraryDirectories:
C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\lib64
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib

Linker/Input: 
mysqlcppconn.lib
libmysql.lib
```

running VS 2019 and MySQL Connector C++ 8.0 and yeah.. so any help would great thanks!

side note Interestingly the mysql.h from the MySQL Server 8.0/include Folder does seem to get recognized.

Comment: we can't help you as we don't ko the layout of your foder in relation to your code, but when VS tells you it can't find it, it is is actually so. check th include directories, if the files are in them

Comment: The problem is that your "include headers" configuration is incorrect.  1) I assume you're configuring headers in the MSVS IDE: `MSVS > Project > Configuration > VC++ Directories > Include directories`. 2) Be sure to separate your paths with a semicolon (`;`).  EXAMPLE: `C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\include;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include; A:\Program Files\boost_1_74_0\boost_1_74_0`, 3) Use double-quotes, not angle brackets/  EXAMPLE: `#include "myheader.h"`

Comment: PS: You're getting a *compile* error.  You haven't gotten as as far as linking any "libraries" yet ;)  Fix the ";", and I'll bet you'll be in much better shape ;)

Comment: Hey guys thanks for your feed back i added a screen shot for better understanding, NBK to answer your statement I did make sure that the includ folder was there with that being said, interestingly the include folder actually contains more folders not libraries, could that be part of the problem? should i remove the files from those folders and add all the files to the main include folder?

Comment: Paulsm4 i will give that a try thanks you!